# mongoose how can I get the last message for each conversation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema for messages and I want to query all conversation of a user.

I want to use same scheme for conversations list and messages.(I tried to separate them but it did not work.) All I want to do is to be able to fetch chat list.

The last message and the one you are messaging with.

```
const messengerScheme = mongoose.Schema({ 
    users:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }],
    from:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    message:{
        type:String,
    },
    hasImage:{
        type:Boolean,
    },
    image:{
        type:String
    }
})
```

Suppose two users has a conversation like the following:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609ee8c7593cda1de475cfff"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988"), 
        ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4")
    ],
    "from" : ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988"),
    "message" : "Hiiii",
    "hasImage" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:16:55.318Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:16:55.318Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609ee8e5593cda1de475d000"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4"), 
        ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988")
    ],
    "from" : ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4"),
    "message" : "hiiii !",
    "hasImage" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:17:25.723Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:17:25.723Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609ee8ec593cda1de475d001"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4"), 
        ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988")
    ],
    "from" : ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4"),
    "message" : "how are you ?",
    "hasImage" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:17:32.686Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:17:32.686Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("609ee90b593cda1de475d002"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988"), 
        ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4")
    ],
    "from" : ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988"),
    "message" : "I am pretty fine, what about you ?",
    "hasImage" : false,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:18:03.224Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-05-14T21:18:03.224Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

When I query with a user ID "6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4", I just want to fetch the last message and the user profile populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match` user id with `users`
- `$sort` by `updatedAt` in descending order
- `$limit` 1 message in result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { users: ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4") } },
  { $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g2T4U9-PoHA)

---

Conversation wise latest single message:

- `$match` user id with `users`
- `$sort` by `updatedAt` in descending order
- `$setUnion` to sort `users` in a order
- `$group` by above sorted `users` and get first root document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { users: ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4") } },
  { $sort: { updatedAt: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $setUnion: "$users" },
      message: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IPF7eRmb4oV)

Comment: It works perfectly fine but What I want to have is a bit different than the outcome it generates, this returned the last message of the conversation between  two users  ObjectId("60841c75b6c2a522047d1988") and ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4") , I want also return other last messages of other conversations that our user has, suppose our user ObjectId("6084036ad4d4cd40a47afba4") also has a similar conversation with user  ObjectId("60841d03f6ccad2b0400f619"), it should return the last message of that conversation too

Comment: how to determine a user conversation?

Comment: I tried to use another collection called conversations where two user take place in a array but at that time I could not get last message in each conversation , const conversationScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    users:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    time:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    },
})

Comment: So I thought maybe I can get the conversation list directly from the messages scheme, and the latest messages could be obtained from that

Comment: i don't think this is good approach to determine a conversation by `users` array, for ex: when one message have `users: [1 ,2]` and second message have `users: [2,1]` so both are different value, $group will consider both values are different.

Comment: see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IPF7eRmb4oV), will give conversation wise first latest message.